# AWK command for sum 2 files

Tags: unix, awk

i am new at awk and i need awk command to summing 2 files if found the same column

file 1

```
a | 16:00 | 24
b | 16:00 | 12
c | 16:00 | 32
```

file 2

```
b | 16:00 | 10
c | 16:00 | 5
d | 16:00 | 14
```

and the output should be

```
a | 16:00 | 24
b | 16:00 | 22
c | 16:00 | 37
d | 16:00 | 14
```

i have read some of the question here and still found the correct way to do it, i already tried with this command

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; FNR=NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{print $0,a[$1]}'
```

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script also uses `sort` but it will work,

```
awk -F'|'  ' { f[$1] += $3 ; g[$1] = $2 } END { for (a in f) { print a , "|",  g[a] , "|",  f[a] } } '   a.txt b.txt | sort
```

The results are

```
    a  |  16:00  | 24
    b  |  16:00  | 22
    c  |  16:00  | 37
    d  |  16:00  | 14
```

Comment: Nice! Note you can also say `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` so that you can then use `print a, g[a], f[a]` instead of hardcoding the pipes there.

Comment: @fedorqui, you are right. Actually I think the first `sort` can be replaced with `cat` too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, or just process the two files all together. See my answer.

Comment: you are right, awk is able to process two/more files as input. your answer needs `sort` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

without `|sort`

```
awk -F'|' '{O[$1FS$2]+=$3}END{asorti(O,T,"@ind_str_asc");for(t in T)print T[t] FS O[T[t]]}' file[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store all the data in two arrays `a[]` and `b[]` and then print them back:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     {a[$1]+=$3; b[$1]=$2}
     END{for (i in a) print i,b[i],a[i]}' f1 f2
```

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {a[$1]+=$3; b[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i,b[i],a[i]}' f1 f2
b | 16:00 |22
c | 16:00 |37
d | 16:00 |14
a | 16:00 |24
```